# sonatype private maven repository response 401 with admin authentication

Tags: maven, sbt, sonatype

I'm install a private maven with [nexus-3.0.0-03-mac.dmg](http://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype)

in `build.sbt` credential with admin and I'm sure the password is right

```
...
credentials += Credentials("local","localhost:7070","admin","admin123")

publishTo <<= version { (v: String) =>
    Some("releases"  at "http://localhost:7070/nexus/repository/maven-releases/")
}
...
```

with cmd: `sbt publish` get errors

```
 Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.lorancechen:rxsocket_2.11:jar:0.9.4 from/to releases (http://localhost:7070/nexus/repository/maven-releases/): Unauthorized (401)
```

I don't know why get 401 even though use admin.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the realm name from "local" to "Sonatype Nexus".

```
credentials += Credentials("Sonatype Nexus","localhost:7070","admin","admin123")
```

Note that we will be changing the realm name in Nexus 3.1 to "Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" to match the current Nexus 2.x realm name:

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10390